# drupal image upload programmaticaly

Tags: 7

i am using drupal 7 . and i am trying to upload image progrmatically .. here is my code

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://drupal.org/files/issues/druplicon_2.png'); // string
$file = file_save_data($image, 'public://druplicon.png',FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
print_r($file); exit
```

and here is my output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [fid] => 4
    [uri] => public://druplicon.png
    [filename] => druplicon.png
    [filemime] => image/png
    [uid] => 1
    [status] => 1
    [timestamp] => 1378142542
    [filesize] => 0
)
```

now here filesize is 0 . as file doesnot contain any data.  i am working on local m/c.  here is no issue of permission. 
Does anybody tell me how to solve this

Thanks

Comment: I agree with @Daniel Verite answer. In addition please remember that `drupal.org` is using `https` protocol for some time now. You can test your code using another source, e.g: `$image_uri = system_retrieve_file('http://ipsumimage.appspot.com/140x100.png'); $image = image_load($image_uri); drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($image, true) . '</pre>');`

Comment: @Jack-PL: i tried above code. this is not working .

Comment: I tested this code and it is working. I wrote the answer with results.

Answer (score 2):

The ability for `file_get_contents()` to fetch contents from an HTTP server depends on the [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) parameter in `php.ini`

If it's not set, `$image` will be false and saving this leads to an empty file.

You may use Drupal's [`system_retrieve_file()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/7) instead. It's a wrapper on top of [`drupal_http_request()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) that comes with its own HTTP client implementation.

Example:

```
$file = system_retrieve_file('http://drupal.org/files/issues/druplicon_2.png',
                             'public://druplicon.png', false,  FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

Comment: @Daneil : allow_url_fopen=on.  still filesize=0. Can u give me example code of system_retrieve_file

Comment: @Rajat: OK. But you should test `$image` after the load  to know whether it's this or the save that fails. There are other reasons why an http request could fail,  like a network security policy.

Comment: Can u tell me how to test it. i m newbie in drupal

Comment: HTTP error -1695770671 occurred when trying to fetch http://drupal.org/files/issues/druplicon_2.png

Comment: @Rajat: so it looks like your server is not allowed to issue external http requests (although the error code is not very informative).

Comment: yeah. i am checking this on local m/c.

Answer (score 0):

```
$image_uri = system_retrieve_file('http://ipsumimage.appspot.com/140x100.png'); 
$image = image_load($image_uri); 
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($image, true) . '</pre>');
```

**result**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [source] => public://140x100.png
    [info] => Array
        (
            [width] => 140
            [height] => 100
            [extension] => png
            [mime_type] => image/png
            [file_size] => 2534
        )

    [toolkit] => gd
    [resource] => Resource id #443
)
```

**Do not use use drupal.org images for testing.**

If you will use drupal.org path, then you can get the following errors:

**using http protocol**

```
HTTP error -5 occurred when trying to fetch http://drupal.org/files/issues/druplicon_2.png
```

**using https protocol**

```
HTTP error 0 occurred when trying to fetch https://drupal.org/files/issues/druplicon_2.png.
```